# how to get referrer from a redirected url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http-referer, http-redirect

I have an url

`domain.com/a`

which redirects to

`domain.com/controller/action/a` .

How do I get the referrer (i.e domain.com/a) in my action for domain.com/controller/action/a ?

One option was to add the referring domain as a parameter .

`domain.com/controller/action/a?referral=domain.com/a` .

Is there a way to get the referrer without passing old referrer as a parameter. Like we would get from `**request.referrer**`. request.referrer doesn't seem to work with redirected urls.

I am using Ruby on Rails for my development.

Comment: @okliv actually I forgot which one I used for my code :) .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I store the referrer path in the session right before redirection

```
session[:referrer]=url_for(params)
```

and then use it where I need it via `session[:referrer]`.

Comment: I guess there isn't other ways

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are looking for the `request.referrer` property: http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html#M000280

Answer (score 4):

We use this line in our application_controller.rb to save the http_referer when a visitor visits our site:

`session[:http_referer] = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]`

Later on, we will save the value into our model for tracking.

Answer (score 0):

May be late, but just to add on. I think it is important to remove the session after using it.

```
redirect_to session.delete(:referrer)
```